# Discord.py nickname command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
  @commands.group(aliases=['nick'], invoke_without_command=True)
  async def nickname(self,ctx):
              embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, use the proper format. [-help].", color=discord.Color.orange())
              return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)


  @nickname.group()
  async def add(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, *, new_name):
    if len(new_name) > 32:
                embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, provide 32 > members.", color=discord.Color.orange())
                return await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)

    elif member.top_role > ctx.author.top_role:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, targets role in the hierarchy is higher than yours.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
    elif ctx.me.top_role <= member.top_role:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, my role in the hierarchy lesser than targets.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
    elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, owners nickname can't be changed.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
          return
    else:
        try:
            await member.edit(nick=new_name)
            embed = discord.Embed(description = "<:ocheckmark:839069223749812264>    "+f"**Successfully changed {member.name}s nickname to {new_name}** ", color = discord.Colour.orange())
            await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
  @nickname.group(aliases=['rem'])
  async def remove(self,ctx,member: discord.Member):
                 if member.top_role > ctx.author.top_role:
                       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, targets role in the hierarchy is higher than yours.", color=discord.Color.orange())
                       await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
                 elif ctx.me.top_role <= member.top_role:
                       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, my role in the hierarchy lesser than targets.", color=discord.Color.orange())
                       await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
                 elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
                       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, owners nickname can't be changed.", color=discord.Color.orange())
                       await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
                       return
                 else:
                     try:
                         name = member.name
                         await member.edit(nick=name)
                         embed = discord.Embed(description = "<:ocheckmark:839069223749812264>    "+f"**Successfully removed {member.name}s nickname** ", color = discord.Colour.orange())
                         await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
                     except Exception as e:
                                 print(e)
  @nickname.error
  async def nickname_error(self,ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
          embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, I can't find that user in this guild.", color=discord.Color.orange())
          await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

I made a command that changes the nickname of another user, although it works just fine there are a few flaws. Firstly if I try to change the owners nickname it only prints out `403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` meaning that `elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:` failed. Lastly if I provide an invalid member, it does not reply neither prints out an error.

Comment: No, I don't think the 403 Forbidden text means `elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:` failed. The code failed because it is literally what the error said - `Missing Permissions`. In discord the bot can't change a nickname of an user when either the bot doesn't have permissions or other user has a higher hierarchy role than you.

Comment: You can't change the nickname of the server owner via bot/the administrator, if I am correct.

Comment: @TKperson @dominik, I mean- its missing permissions because it cant ban the owner to counter that I made ``elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
                       embed = discord.Embed(description="<:oxmark:839069221207670804>  "+f"Unsuccessful, owners nickname can't be changed.", color=discord.Color.orange())
                       await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
                       return`` Which is obviously not working

Comment: Because you're comparing an integer (the ID of `member`) to `Guild.owner` which is a `discord.Member` instance.

Comment: @Rohan What do you mean "cant ban the owner" I thought this was a question about changing nicknames

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
```

Can you replace and try it again with this:

```
elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner.id:
```